# Apache segfault glibc segfault

Tags: apache-2.2, php, segmentation-fault

I keep getting (about every 5-6 hours) this segfault in apache:

```
[Tue Jun 26 12:43:10 2012] [notice] child pid 26810 exit signal Aborted (6)
*** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/apache2: free(): invalid pointer: 0xb68c2628 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6ff22)[0xb75aef22]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bc2)[0xb75afbc2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb75b2cad]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(destroy_zend_class+0x228)[0xb5d40518]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(zend_hash_clean+0x77)[0xb5d58957]
/usr/lib/php5/220100525+lfs/apc.so(apc_interned_strings_shutdown+0x32)[0xb64930b2]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(+0x318ff0)[0xb5d56ff0]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(zend_hash_graceful_reverse_destroy+0x27)[0xb5d58a67]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(zend_destroy_modules+0x3c)[0xb5d506cc]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(+0x30c743)[0xb5d4a743]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(php_module_shutdown+0x42)[0xb5ce5172]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(php_module_shutdown_wrapper+0x17)[0xb5ce5257]
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so(+0x3bebe1)[0xb5dfcbe1]
/usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0(+0x19846)[0xb76f2846]
/usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0(apr_pool_destroy+0x52)[0xb76f19ec]
/usr/sbin/apache2(+0x4ccee)[0xb77eccee]
======= Memory map: ========
b2e18000-b2e2c000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 8841030    /dev/zero (deleted)
b2e2c000-b2eaa000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 8841029    /dev/zero (deleted)
b2eaa000-b2eab000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2eab000-b36ab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5900000-b5921000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5921000-b5a00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5a3e000-b60bd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 44137      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
b60bd000-b611e000 r--p 0067f000 ca:00 44137      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
b611e000-b6123000 rw-p 006e0000 ca:00 44137      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
b6123000-b6142000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6142000-b6147000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 24570      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.13.so
b6147000-b6148000 r--p 00004000 ca:00 24570      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.13.so
b6148000-b6149000 rw-p 00005000 ca:00 24570      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.13.so
b6149000-b6175000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6175000-b6180000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 24572      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
b6180000-b6181000 r--p 0000a000 ca:00 24572      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
b6181000-b6182000 rw-p 0000b000 ca:00 24572      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
b6182000-b618c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 24576      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
b618c000-b618d000 r--p 00009000 ca:00 24576      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
b618d000-b618e000 rw-p 0000a000 ca:00 24576      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
b618e000-b6196000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 24562      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
b6196000-b6197000 r--p 00007000 ca:00 24562      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
b6197000-b6198000 rw-p 00008000 ca:00 24562      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
b6198000-b6270000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6270000-b6274000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6468000-b6474000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6475000-b6479000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6479000-b649a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 65670      /usr/lib/php5/220100525+lfs/apc.so
b649a000-b649b000 r--p 00021000 ca:00 65670      /usr/lib/php5/220100525+lfs/apc.so
b649b000-b649c000 rw-p 00022000 ca:00 65670      /usr/lib/php5/220100525+lfs/apc.so
b649c000-b64a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b64a1000-b64a6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b64a7000-b64aa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b64aa000-b64af000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b64b0000-b64b3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b64bf000-b64c4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b64c4000-b64c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b64c9000-b64cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b64cd000-b64cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b64ea000-b64fd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 24598      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
b64fd000-b64fe000 r--p 00012000 ca:00 24598      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
b64fe000-b64ff000 rw-p 00013000 ca:00 24598      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.13.so
b64ff000-b6501000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b650e000-b652a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 22450      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b652a000-b652b000 r--p 0001b000 ca:00 22450      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b652b000-b652c000 rw-p 0001c000 ca:00 22450      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b652c000-b6534000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b65dd000-b65df000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b67ad000-b67c2000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 22063      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
b67c2000-b67c3000 r--p 00015000 ca:00 22063      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
b67c3000-b67c4000 rw-p 00016000 ca:00 22063      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
b67c4000-b67c6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b67c6000-b67ee000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 21904      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
b67ee000-b67ef000 r--p 00028000 ca:00 21904      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
b67ef000-b67f0000 rw-p 00029000 ca:00 21904      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
b67f0000-b67f7000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 24600      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
b67f7000-b67f8000 r--p 00006000 ca:00 24600      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
b67f8000-b67f9000 rw-p 00007000 ca:00 24600      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
b6886000-b69af000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b69af000-b6b3c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 23592      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
b6b3c000-b6b4a000 r--p 0018d000 ca:00 23592      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
b6b4a000-b6b50000 rw-p 0019b000 ca:00 23592      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
b6b50000-b6b53000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6b53000-b6b9b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 23621      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
b6b9b000-b6b9d000 r--p 00047000 ca:00 23621      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
b6b9d000-b6ba0000 rw-p 00049000 ca:00 23621      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
b6ba0000-b6c7e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 9878       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
b6c7e000-b6c7f000 ---p 000de000 ca:00 9878       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
b6c7f000-b6c83000 r--p 000de000 ca:00 9878       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
b6c83000-b6c84000 rw-p 000e2000 ca:00 9878       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
b6c84000-b6c8b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6c93000-b6cd4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6cd4000-b6ce0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6cea000-b6cef000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45178      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_status.so
b6cef000-b6cf0000 r--p 00004000 ca:00 45178      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_status.so
b6cf0000-b6cf1000 rw-p 00005000 ca:00 45178      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_status.so
b6cf1000-b6d19000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45175      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
b6d19000-b6d1a000 ---p 00028000 ca:00 45175      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
b6d1a000-b6d1b000 r--p 00028000 ca:00 45175      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
b6d1b000-b6d1c000 rw-p 00029000 ca:00 45175      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
b6d1c000-b6d1e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6d1e000-b6d20000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45166      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so
b6d20000-b6d21000 r--p 00001000 ca:00 45166      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so
b6d21000-b6d22000 rw-p 00002000 ca:00 45166      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so
b6d22000-b6d30000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45195      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
b6d30000-b6d31000 r--p 0000e000 ca:00 45195      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
b6d31000-b6d32000 rw-p 0000f000 ca:00 45195      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
b6d32000-b6d45000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45168      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
b6d45000-b6d46000 r--p 00012000 ca:00 45168      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
b6d46000-b6d47000 rw-p 00013000 ca:00 45168      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
b6d47000-b6d4e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 9904       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
b6d4e000-b6d4f000 r--p 00006000 ca:00 9904       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
b6d4f000-b6d50000 rw-p 00007000 ca:00 9904       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
b6d50000-b6e97000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 3416       /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
b6e97000-b6e9b000 r--p 00147000 ca:00 3416       /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
b6e9b000-b6e9c000 rw-p 0014b000 ca:00 3416       /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
b6e9c000-b6e9d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6e9d000-b6ec4000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 12282      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
b6ec4000-b6ec5000 r--p 00026000 ca:00 12282      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
b6ec5000-b6ec6000 rw-p 00027000 ca:00 12282      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
b6ec6000-b6f88000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 13335      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
b6f88000-b6f8e000 r--p 000c1000 ca:00 13335      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
b6f8e000-b6f8f000 rw-p 000c7000 ca:00 13335      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
b6f8f000-b6fca000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 9854       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
b6fca000-b6fcb000 ---p 0003b000 ca:00 9854       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
b6fcb000-b6fcc000 r--p 0003b000 ca:00 9854       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
b6fcc000-b6fcd000 rw-p 0003c000 ca:00 9854       /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
b6fcd000-b6fdc000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 21797      /lib/libbz2.so.1.0.4
b6fdc000-b6fdd000 r--p 0000e000 ca:00 21797      /lib/libbz2.so.1.0.4
b6fdd000-b6fde000 rw-p 0000f000 ca:00 21797      /lib/libbz2.so.1.0.4
b6fde000-b702a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 2505       /usr/lib/libqdbm.so.14.13.0
b702a000-b702b000 r--p 0004c000 ca:00 2505       /usr/lib/libqdbm.so.14.13.0
b702b000-b702c000 rw-p 0004d000 ca:00 2505       /usr/lib/libqdbm.so.14.13.0
b702c000-b71aa000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 10201      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdb-4.8.so
b71aa000-b71ac000 r--p 0017d000 ca:00 10201      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdb-4.8.so
b71ac000-b71ad000 rw-p 0017f000 ca:00 10201      /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdb-4.8.so
b71ad000-b71f7000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 23521      /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
b71f7000-b71f8000 r--p 0004a000 ca:00 23521      /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
b71f8000-b71fb000 rw-p 0004b000 ca:00 23521      /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
b71fb000-b7359000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 835379     /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
b7359000-b735a000 ---p 0015e000 ca:00 835379     /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
b735a000-b7362000 r--p 0015e000 ca:00 835379     /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
b7362000-b7371000 rw-p 00166000 ca:00 835379     /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
b7371000-b7374000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7374000-b73ba000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 2503       /usr/lib/libonig.so.2.0.0
b73ba000-b73bd000 rw-p 00045000 ca:00 2503       /usr/lib/libonig.so.2.0.0
b73be000-b73c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b73c0000-b73c7000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45171      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
b73c7000-b73c8000 r--p 00006000 ca:00 45171      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
b73c8000-b73c9000 rw-p 00007000 ca:00 45171      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
b73c9000-b73dc000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 22461      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
b73dc000-b73dd000 r--p 00012000 ca:00 22461      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
b73dd000-b73de000 rw-p 00013000 ca:00 22461      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
b73de000-b73e3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b73e3000-b73ea000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45188      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_negotiation.so
b73ea000-b73eb000 r--p 00006000 ca:00 45188      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_negotiation.so
b73eb000-b73ec000 rw-p 00007000 ca:00 45188      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_negotiation.so
b73ec000-b73f1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b73f2000-b73f5000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45149      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
b73f5000-b73f6000 r--p 00002000 ca:00 45149      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
b73f6000-b73f7000 rw-p 00003000 ca:00 45149      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
b73f7000-b73fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b73fc000-b73fe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b73fe000-b7400000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 22437      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.3
b7400000-b7401000 r--p 00001000 ca:00 22437      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.3
b7401000-b7402000 rw-p 00002000 ca:00 22437      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.3
b7402000-b7407000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7407000-b7409000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 22344      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
b7409000-b740a000 r--p 00001000 ca:00 22344      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
b740a000-b740b000 rw-p 00002000 ca:00 22344      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
b740b000-b7410000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7411000-b7413000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7413000-b7416000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7416000-b7418000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7418000-b741c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45176      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
b741c000-b741d000 r--p 00003000 ca:00 45176      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
b741d000-b741e000 rw-p 00004000 ca:00 45176      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
b741e000-b7422000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45162      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
b7422000-b7423000 r--p 00003000 ca:00 45162      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
b7423000-b7424000 rw-p 00004000 ca:00 45162      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
b7424000-b7426000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45161      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_expires.so
b7426000-b7427000 r--p 00001000 ca:00 45161      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_expires.so
b7427000-b7428000 rw-p 00002000 ca:00 45161      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_expires.so
b7428000-b742a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45189      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so
b742a000-b742b000 r--p 00001000 ca:00 45189      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so
b742b000-b742c000 rw-p 00002000 ca:00 45189      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so
b742c000-b742e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b742f000-b7430000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45158      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_env.so
b7430000-b7431000 r--p 00000000 ca:00 45158      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_env.so
b7431000-b7432000 rw-p 00001000 ca:00 45158      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_env.so
b7432000-b7437000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7437000-b743c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45155      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
b743c000-b743d000 r--p 00004000 ca:00 45155      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
b743d000-b743e000 rw-p 00005000 ca:00 45155      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
b743e000-b7443000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7443000-b7448000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45184      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgi.so
b7448000-b7449000 r--p 00004000 ca:00 45184      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgi.so
b7449000-b744a000 rw-p 00005000 ca:00 45184      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgi.so
b744a000-b744f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b744f000-b7457000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45179      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_autoindex.so
b7457000-b7458000 r--p 00007000 ca:00 45179      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_autoindex.so
b7458000-b7459000 rw-p 00008000 ca:00 45179      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_autoindex.so
b7459000-b745e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b745e000-b745f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45136      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_user.so
b745f000-b7460000 r--p 00000000 ca:00 45136      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_user.so
b7460000-b7461000 rw-p 00001000 ca:00 45136      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_user.so
b7461000-b7466000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7466000-b7468000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45134      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so
b7468000-b7469000 r--p 00001000 ca:00 45134      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so
b7469000-b746a000 rw-p 00002000 ca:00 45134      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so
b746a000-b746f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b746f000-b7471000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45135      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
b7471000-b7472000 r--p 00001000 ca:00 45135      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
b7472000-b7473000 rw-p 00002000 ca:00 45135      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
b7473000-b7478000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7478000-b7479000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45140      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so
b7479000-b747a000 r--p 00000000 ca:00 45140      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so
b747a000-b747b000 rw-p 00001000 ca:00 45140      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so
b747b000-b7480000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7480000-b7481000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 44436      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_file.so
b7481000-b7482000 ---p 00001000 ca:00 44436      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_file.so
b7482000-b7483000 r--p 00001000 ca:00 44436      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_file.so
b7483000-b7484000 rw-p 00002000 ca:00 44436      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_file.so
b7484000-b7489000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7489000-b748b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45141      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
b748b000-b748c000 r--p 00001000 ca:00 45141      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
b748c000-b748d000 rw-p 00002000 ca:00 45141      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
b748d000-b7492000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7492000-b7495000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 45194      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
b7495000-b7496000 r--p 00002000 ca:00 45194      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
b7496000-b7497000 rw-p 00003000 ca:00 45194      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
b7497000-b74d8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b74d8000-b74db000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 21902      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
b74db000-b74dc000 r--p 00002000 ca:00 21902      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
b74dc000-b74dd000 rw-p 00003000 ca:00 21902      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
b74dd000-b74de000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b74de000-b74e2000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 22401      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
b74e2000-b74e3000 r--p 00003000 ca:00 22401      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
b74e3000-b74e4000 rw-p 00004000 ca:00 22401      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
b74e4000-b750a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 22420      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
b750a000-b750b000 ---p 00026000 ca:00 22420      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
b750b000-b750d000 r--p 00026000 ca:00 22420      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
b750d000-b750e000 rw-p 00028000 ca:00 22420      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
b750e000-b7516000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 21889      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
b7516000-b7517000 r--p 00007000 ca:00 21889      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
b7517000-b7518000 rw-p 00008000 ca:00 21889      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
b7518000-b753f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b753f000-b76b7000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 21864      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
b76b7000-b76b9000 r--p 00178000 ca:00 21864      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
b76b9000-b76ba000 rw-p 0017a000 ca:00 21864      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
b76ba000-b76bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76bd000-b76d4000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 24594      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
b76d4000-b76d5000 r--p 00016000 ca:00 24594      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
b76d5000-b76d6000 rw-p 00017000 ca:00 24594      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
b76d6000-b76d9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76d9000-b770c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 6233       /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.5
b770c000-b770d000 r--p 00032000 ca:00 6233       /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.5
b770d000-b770e000 rw-p 00033000 ca:00 6233       /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.5
b770e000-b772f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 6236       /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0.3.12
b772f000-b7730000 r--p 00020000 ca:00 6236       /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0.3.12
b7730000-b7731000 rw-p 00021000 ca:00 6236       /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0.3.12
b7731000-b776e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 22336      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.12.1
b776e000-b776f000 r--p 0003c000 ca:00 22336      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.12.1
b776f000-b7770000 rw-p 0003d000 ca:00 22336      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.12.1
b7770000-b7780000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7780000-b779e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 21844      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
b779e000-b779f000 r--p 0001d000 ca:00 21844      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
b779f000-b77a0000 rw-p 0001e000 ca:00 21844      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
b77a0000-b7803000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 44432      /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
b7803000-b7805000 r--p 00063000 ca:00 44432      /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
b7805000-b7807000 rw-p 00065000 ca:00 44432      /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
b7807000-b780a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7a17000-b7a55000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7a55000-b7b9f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7b9f000-b7c1a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
bf9a1000-bf9c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
f57fe000-f57ff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
[Tue Jun 26 13:15:10 2012] [notice] child pid 26840 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

Sometimes it recovers, but sometimes it kills the server. It's unclear to me what glibc is doing to crash.. can anyone decipher what's crashing in this error log?

Comment: I did recently turn on `extension=apc.so` for the first time.. not sure if I have to turn something else off after doing this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.4.x, then the latest stable version of APC (3.1.9) won't work.  You need 3.1.10, which is listed currently as beta.  So:

```
 pear install apc-beta
```

should do it.

Comment: hmm `pear install apc-beta` didn't work, but after a pear channel update, `pecl install apc-beta` seems to be installing 3.1.10. I will give this a shot! thanks

Answer (score 1):

At least php-fpm + APC is [a known problematic combination](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60462&edit=1). Might also affect PHP 5.4.x + APC, too, regardless what mode (mod_php, php-fpm, suPHP ...) your PHP is running on. It's APC which is buggy in this case.

Disabling APC should help. Have you tried [XCache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/) instead?

Comment: I tried apt installing php5-xcache, but was getting `php5-xcache : Depends: phpapi-20090626+lfs`.. probably doesn't play nice with 5.4 either..

Answer (score 0):

according to http://xcache.lighttpd.net/, XCache 2.0.0 works with PHP 5.4, not sure if your linux distro contain up to date PHP and XCache
btw, PHP 5.3 up to 5.3.14 is unstable