# glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/httpd: free(): invalid pointer

Tags: centos, glibc

One of my websites gives a lot of internal server errors. When I restart httpd they are gone for a while. But after some time they come back. And once or twice they have frozen the whole server/VPS.

When I check the log files I come across these errors: 
    *** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/httpd: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f1d55342fa8 ***
And sometimes also preceded with: 
    zend_mm_heap corrupted

I am running CentOS 6.5 and use VestaCP as a hosting control panel. VestaCP installed Apache/2.2.15, PHP 5.4.21, APC 3.1.15

My server runs 4-5 tiny websites on a VPS with 4GB RAM. The site giving the problems is build with Drupal 7. My other websites are build with Laravel and don't seem to cause any problems. But I am not sure if it is a problem with that Drupal website or server configuration.

I found these similar problems, but the first one is not the answer for me. And the second one, I'm not sure what to do with it.
 - [Apache segfault glibc segfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/402494/apache-segfault-glibc-segfault)
 - [CentOS 6 Httpd failed to start](https://serverfault.com/questions/571998/centos-6-httpd-failed-to-start)

Can anyone show me the right direction to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: APC is known to be buggy. Get rid of it. If that doesn't help, look for defective hardware, probably RAM.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I disabled APC. I will check if this solves it and let you know. Is there an APC alternative you can recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't experienced any problems since I disabled APC as suggested by Michael Hampton, the problems seems to be solved. No more APC for me. Thanks Michael.

Comment: The official replacement for APC is [Zend OPcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php).